# Magento Plugin won't show up in admin

Tags: magento

I have a custome payment method module.I install magento on windows 7 (Wamp) and the module works perfectly. However when i try to install the same on Linux(Lamp), i donot see the module in the backend. 
My module installs a table into the DB on startup. On my linux server even the installer script fails to run. The only sign on the module in Linux installation is at system->configuration->advanced->disable modules output.

I would really appreciate if someone would give me ideas on how to solve this. Thank you so much!

Comment: if you seen my answer give some response.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply.Messed up my laptop.Although as a follow up - This works on localhost but some of my clients are having problems on their live hosted sites.I am assuming that they might need to do some other configurations as well specific to their server.Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring due to file/folder permission. Change the Linux permissions for all files in your Magento base directory to readable and writable by the owning user (you).Set permissions to 664 for files and 775 for folders. 775 for files will work too. Set 777 for media and var , only 2 folders need to be writable by everyone.thanks.